# HTML & CSS Vertical Scrollbar Indicator

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create something that is similar to this website's vertical scrollable bar and containers:

[image: This is what I'm trying to achieve]

Basically, I have several divs in my website, I want to be able to scroll through them. Meaning, I want to create something that is similar to the vertical scroll bar which indicates in which section I'm in as well as create a transition between the sections when I scroll.

I've tried looking for several things but I don't know the proper terminologies so I'm not finding what I want.

How do I achieve that?

I'm not asking for the code I just want to know the proper things I should research and try out.

Thank you.

Comment: do you mean the animated section when you scroll through them ?

Comment: @ths Yes, this entire vertical scroll bar and its containers.

Comment: edit your post and add an image for the specified thing you want to achieve.

Comment: @ths Sorry I'm having trouble explaining what I want to achieve. If you still didn't understand what I mean please let me know.

Comment: You can add div's/buttons and design/position them accordingly and then link them to their functionalities. Actually, the website you provided in your question can be achieved by simply adding the id in the `href`. But that is left to your imagination.

Comment: @AbhinavAlok But how do I achieve that scrolling bar? Do I create it by buttons?

Comment: Yes, it could be anything from buttons/divs to simple list which you can style according to your requirements. 
Just a tip: Use Inspect element and look for what you need and how they (the page you are looking for inspiration) achieved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a **Fixed Vertical Navigation Bar** or a **Fixed Sidebar**.

Basically, it's just a simple navigation bar, but it has the `right: 0` CSS rules to it to force it on the side. Then, it uses width to keep it vertical and the usual text on a nav bar is replaced with dots. Finally, it auto-scrolls you to whichever part of the page you want to get to by using hashes with element ID's.

Here are a few links to get you started on creating one of your own:

1. [Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/damonbauer/pen/ECdhG) (replace text that says "link" with middle dots)
2. [W3Schools Example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_sidebar.asp) (again, replacing text with middle dots)
3. [Treehouse Example](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-to-make-a-left-vertical-navigation-bar-like-the-one-on-treehouse) (a thread that links to many other ideas)

Here's a really rudimentary example:

```css
.left {
  position:fixed;
  top: 30%; left: 0;
  height:100%; width:50px; 
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">•</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">•</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">•</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">•</a></li>
    <li><a href="#5">•</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!